# Loading an activity before launch

Tags: android, asynchronous, progressdialog

I have an activity that contains a button, when you press the button it loads a second activity. The second activity has a listView and a bunch of other stuff and on most devices takes a few seconds to load so I want to display a progressDialog to let the user know that the activity is in fact loading. I have the following:

EDIT:

```
public void rewardFirstNext(View view){

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> progress = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading Installed Applications");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            PackageManager mPackageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<Applications> packageInfoListApps = new ArrayList<Applications>();
            List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = mPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            List<PackageInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

            for (PackageInfo apps : packageInfoList) {
                if (!isSystemPackage(apps)) {
                    installedApps.add(apps);
                }

            }
            Collections.sort(installedApps, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                public int compare(PackageInfo o1, PackageInfo o2) {
                    return o1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
                }
            });
            for (PackageInfo apps : installedApps) {
                packageInfoListApps.add(new Applications(apps, false, false));
            }

            //what else happens here?
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    progress.execute((Void[]) null);
}
```

Comment: The problem is what you are doing does not give you want you want it to. ie. it does not load the content into the listview. all you are doing is starting an activity from a background thread and nothing more. You need to post what you are loading in the list and how you are doing it

Comment: I might be wrong as I haven't done Android for a while, but as you are launching an activity in doInBackground(), would the onPostExecute() only run once you have ended the newly launched activity? (The doInBackground would continue until the new activity has finished)

Comment: @StuWhyte the whole thing is wrong, he should not be using an asynctask to launch an activity. but no it will not run because the calling activity will be destroyed then he starts the new activity

Comment: I realized that as soon as I tried running it once, the launch goes in onPostExecute() what confuses me is what goes in doInBackground(). Added details above concerning what needs to get loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be doing is putting all of this

```
mPackageManager = getPackageManager();
List<Applications> packageInfoListApps = new ArrayList<Applications>();
List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = mPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
List<PackageInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

for (PackageInfo apps : packageInfoList) {
    if (!isSystemPackage(apps)) {
        installedApps.add(apps);
    }

}
Collections.sort(installedApps, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
    public int compare(PackageInfo o1, PackageInfo o2) {
        return o1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
    }
});
for (PackageInfo apps : installedApps) {
    packageInfoListApps.add(new Applications(apps, false, false));
}
```

inside of an asynctask.

take this `new ApplicationAdapter(this, packageInfoListApps, mPackageManager)` and keep a reference of it as in

```
ApplicationAdapter adater = new ApplicationAdapter(this, packageInfoListApps, mPackageManager)
```

Then start your progress dialog like you did and in your onPostCreate call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

which will then populate the listview and you should stop you dialog then too

Comment: Alright, I see why the app loading goes into `doInBackground` but I'm still confused as per how I pass that loaded information into the next activity; I edit the code above, the line above `return null;` is where I assume something hapens, as well as in onPostExecute?

Comment: you dont, you do that in the activity you want it to display in